# Accessing django formset data

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a formset in django that uses a model with a one to many relationship.   Many attendees can attend a single event.

I am sending the 'many' part of the model in a formset.  The problem is that the data is returned with no primary key set.   I am getting a validation error because the formset primary key data is not set.

Back in my view, I know what the primary key is supposed to be.  And i want to set it before validation.  Either that or set the value before I send out the form for display.  But I don't know how to set it in the formset data.

In the code below, foreign key is `event`.

Option 1:  Set the foreign key before showing the form:

```
#models.py  - note 2 foreign keys
class Attendee(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    sponsor = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30) 

# forms.py
class AttendeeForm(forms.ModelForm): 
  event = forms.IntegerField(required=True, widget=forms.HiddenInput()) 

  class Meta: 
    model = Attendee 
    fields = ( 'last_name', 'first_name', ) 
    exclude = ('event', )  # excluded so user can't set foreign key

# views.py
event = get_object_or_404(Event, id=event_id)
AttendeeFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Event, Attendee, form=AttendeeForm, extra=1)
formset = AttendeeFormSet(instance=event, prefix='attendees')
# Error on form submit:  
#  Returns and redisplays the form along with message.
#  (Hidden field event) The inline foreign key did not match the parent instance primary key.


#  I also tried:  
#AttendeeFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Event, Customer, Attendee, form=AttendeeForm, extra=1)
# which gave error: 
# inlineformset_factory() got multiple values for keyword argument 'form'
```

Option 2:  Set the foreign key on the return POST.  Note even though data is present, the form is not valid because foreign key is not set.

```
formset = AttendeeFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='attendees')
i=0
for form in formset.forms:
   # How can I set the foreign key (event) field here?
   pdb.set_trace()

if formset.is_valid():
   attendees = formset.save_all()


(Pdb) p form.fields
{'last_name': <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0xaa44a2c>, 
'first_name':    <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0xaa449ec>,  
'event': <django.forms.fields.IntegerField object at 0xaa44fec>}
(Pdb)
```

What is the best way to fix my foreign key problem in my formset?   If Option 2 How do I set this field before I test `is_valid`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django inline foreign key does not match parent primary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388921/django-inline-foreign-key-does-not-match-parent-primary-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a formset representing a foreign key relationship, you should use [`inlineformset_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) to construct the class. That will take care of setting the FKs for you:

```
AttendeeFormSet = formset_factory(Event, Attendee, form=AttendeeForm)
...
formset = AttendeeFormSet(instance=my_event)
```

Comment: I think this is the closest to success.  But its still not quite working.  I edited the question to clarify the data structure, what I tried, and the results I got.   What next step should I try?

Comment: You probably don't need to exclude the `event` field in the AttendeeForm, as inlineformset_factory will take care of it.

Comment: Actually, you can't use `fields` and `exclude` together in a form anyway - you should add `event` to the `fields` tuple.

Comment: Thanks.  I removed the exclude and added `event` to the tuple.  still getting:  `(Hidden field event) The inline foreign key did not match the parent instance primary key.`   Can you think of anything that would cause that error msg?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `commit=False` to `.save()`, you can then modify the object and add the foreign key.

See [Saving objects in the formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#saving-objects-in-the-formset) for example code.

Comment: I tried this:  `formset.save(commit=False)`  This gave me the following error directed at that line:  `The Attendee could not be created because the data didn't validate.`   Ideas?